# How do I access other extended partitions if I create a linux-swap in one extended partition ?

Tags: root, partitioning

I am asking this because I have tried ubuntu in live session and I couldn't access my extended partition which I created only for data storing and other one is for linux-swap . I checked the disk utility and it says the drive is already mounted . So I tried unmounting and it resulted an error with can't umount: device or resource is busy . I even checked with testdisk it said there is invalid boot sector so I ran advanced file system utils option and repaired the boot sector . Point to be noted : 'previously even windows couldn't recognize the drive but after fixing boot sector it did .' Then I restarted the live session in ubuntu again but alas! The problem still persists . So I backed up the drive from windows machine and reformatted it . I am planning to install ubuntu on the extended partition . So I really need to know will the swap partition cause any problem accessing the root partition if ubuntu is installed in the extended partition also ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; Ubuntu can be entirely installed in an extended partition ( specifically, in logical partitions which live inside the extended partition ).